# Linux Containers (LXC) : lx-execute and networking

Tags: linux, virtualization, virtual-machines, lxc, containers

I have a question about LXC Containers.

I have some containers, if I lxc-start them, they come up with networking fine, but I want to just be able to run commands against them using lxc-execute, without starting the whole thing. However, when I do this, there is no connectivity? - I guess as doesnt run init. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the network is not setup because lxc-execute just creates the container and runs your application. lxc-start runs /sbin/init, which takes care of the nitty-gritty.

You can use a script that sets up networking and then executes whatever you give it as the first parameter, something like:

```
ifup -a
if [ -x "$1" ]; then
    exec "$1"
fi
echo "Something went wrong."
```

You could also configure the network parameters in the container configuration. In this case LXC will set up the network before it runs your application.